# How can I install an SSL certificate for all users on a Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm not particularly familiar with Windows Server, so please bear with me.

I have about 10 users that all use Terminal Services to login to our Windows 2003 server, each with different user accounts. Each of these users also needs to have 8 SSL certificates installed.

At present, when I need to install a new certificate, I have to login to each users account and install the certificate. Or when I add a new user, I have to go and install all 8 certificates for them.

Is there a more streamlined way I can go about doing this, so that I could add the certificate once, and it would propagate to all users?

I should also add that we're not running Active Direcotry. The box is pretty much setup only to run a single piece of software.

Comment: What the f\*\*\* do you need 8 SSL Certificates for? Are you talking about the fact that each users needs to trust 8 certificates, or do they actually USE 8 client certificates?

Comment: They actually use 8 client certificates. The software the users are running need to connect to the PayPal API, but we have 8 different PayPal accounts (I know, I know).

Comment: If your users are members of Administrators on the local machines (I know, I know), you can just add them to Computer Store instead of the individual user certificate stores

Comment: They have to be Administrators though? That is potentially an option actually, only because their accounts run the software they need at login and they can't really get to anything to screw stuff up.... but obviously that's something I'd rather avoid, if possible.